# Finding the index of a list item in jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, indexing

I have an unordered list of eight items. On page load the first five `<li>` have default thumbnail images in them and the 6th one has a 1px by 1px placeholder image with the ID of `$('#last')`. When a user inserts a new image it replaces the 'src' of `$('#last')` with their new image. It's not the most efficient way but it works.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="img1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img2.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img3.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img4.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img5.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="1px.png" id="last"/></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

When the user adds a new image the ID of `$('#last')` is removed and I use `each()` to find the next empty `<li>` and insert the 1px by 1px image in it, with an ID of `$('#last')` so it is ready for the next image upload.

At this point I need to get the `index()` of the `<li>` that now has the 1px by 1px image in it, whose ID is `$('#last')`, so that I can store the index in the session, so when a user comes back to the page the `$('#last')` ID is still set and ready to accept another image.

How do I get the index of the `<li>` with that image in it, since it was set after page load? Is there a way to use `delegate()` or `on()` to get it? i.e. how do I get the index of an element that was set after page load?

Comment: I barely can understand what you're asking about

Comment: Plenty of example here: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 0):

All of the following suggestions are based on the assumption that these snippets of scripts will run *after* the new `li` has been inserted.

To get the index of the last of the `li` elements:

```
var lastLi = $('ul li:last').index();
```

To do this conditionally, checking whether it has the matching `src`:

```
var lastLi = $('ul li').filter(
                 function(){
                     return $(this).attr('src') == '1px.png';
                 });
```

On the assumption that the last `li` will *always* contain the placeholder image:

```
var lastLi = $('#last').index();
```

References:

- [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="img1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img2.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img3.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img4.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img5.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

And every time an image is added:

```
$('ul').append('<li><img src="imgn.png" /></li>');
```

Where "imgn.png" is the name of the new image file. At any point, if you need to know how many images are in the list:

```
$('ul li').length
```

If, however, it's important to always have 8 list elements:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="img1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img2.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img3.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img4.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="img5.png" /></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

function addImage(url){
    $('ul li:empty').first().html('<img src="' + url + '" />');
}
addImage('img6.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can insert < img id="#last"... so to get index() of li that has #last

```
var list = $('#last').parent('li');
alert( $('li').index(list) );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/shahrokhnabavi/qzAth/1/)